# Strange Validation Losses Curve

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I' new in neural network, I built a ANN for regression task. I've plotted the loss function for training and validation. But I'm not sure that it is a good curve. I think this because the val loss go down very steeply. What do you think?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This can happen, take a look at this post:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187404

Comment: Thanks for the post, I have another question for you. As you can see, from 25 epochs val loss increase a little, then it remain flat like the training. is it a syntom of overfitting? I don't think but i'd like a confirm

Comment: It can be a symptom of overfitting, yes.

Comment: Thanks, I added a picture in the post. Now the val loss is different and has a big oscillation. In your opinion what could be the reason?

Comment: In my opinion, beyond 25 epochs it does not make sense to train the model further as your validation loss is more or less constant. If you train the model for more epochs, it might cause overfitting. Few things you can try: 1. Decrease the learning rate of your optimizer to get a more gradual loss curve. 2. Increase the size of your validation data if you can and observe if you are getting similar results.. hope this helps!